# Solving equation involving 2D interpolated function

Tags: equation-solving

I have [this data](https://pastebin.com/DGXpRvjs) making this `ListPlot3D`:

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[trialstuff2, 1], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

I can create an interpolation function:

```
intFunc = Interpolation[Join @@ trialstuff2];
```

I want to find the solutions to the equation `intFunc == 0`  as a y[x] function since it will be in 2D.

How can I do it? 
 I could not get `Solve` to work. Is there a trick to it or do I need to find the intersection between the interpolated function and a plane {x,y,0}?

Comment: Sorry I cannot load the data trialstuff. Could you please provide a small set of data? Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I managed to import the data by changing the file extension from .txt to .m and than using just the Import function.

Comment: @Fraccalo: Thank you for your effort, but I cannot access the link(url)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
f0[x_] = NSolve[intFunc[x, y] == 0, y][[1]]
```

In this way you will obtain a function y[x] where the intFunc[x,y]==0.

For example:

```
(intFunc[#, y /. f0[#]]) & /@ Range[2.5, 4, 0.1] // Chop
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

```
pp0 = {#, y /. f0[#], (intFunc[#, y /. f0[#]])} & /@ Range[2.5, 4, 0.01] // Chop;        
Show[
     ListPlot3D[Flatten[trialstuff2, 1], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
     , ListPointPlot3D[pp0]
     ]
```

[image]

And this is for showing that the intersection is actually in z=0:

```
Show[
 ListPlot3D[Flatten[trialstuff2, 1], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
 , Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
 , ListPointPlot3D[pp0]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: No it still gives no answer

Comment: @Fraccalo, not sure I understand what you propose. Why should you solve for $y$ only, instead of for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @MarcoB I think I misinterpreted the question. I thought the OP was about finding y[x] so that the intFunc is equal to 0. And I thought my solution provided that. For example, if we consider the toy case: a[x_] = Solve[x + y == 0, y] the result gives {{y -> -x}}, which is a y[x] that satisfies the condition of x+y ==0!

Comment: I'll edit the answer to make that clearer.